# How to get just the id of a channel

Tags: discord, bots, discord.js

I have a script where a user can specify a channel to be the welcome channel and it will save the channel in quick.db but when I want to send an embed to the specified channel it won't let me. So I console.log()
and I saw that it returned everything.

```
TextChannel {
  type: 'text',
  deleted: false,
  id: '730763402229841980',
  name: '�┊�è�������',
  rawPosition: 1,
  parentID: '730762991502622752',
  permissionOverwrites: Collection [Map] {},
  topic: null,
  nsfw: false,
  lastMessageID: '739703571565641748',
  rateLimitPerUser: 0,
  lastPinTimestamp: null,
  guild: Guild {
    members: GuildMemberManager {
      cacheType: [Function: Collection],
      cache: [Collection [Map]],
      guild: [Circular]
    },
    channels: GuildChannelManager {
      cacheType: [Function: Collection],
      cache: [Collection [Map]],
      guild: [Circular]
    },
    roles: RoleManager {
      cacheType: [Function: Collection],
      cache: [Collection [Map]],
      guild: [Circular]
    },
    presences: PresenceManager {
      cacheType: [Function: Collection],
      cache: [Collection [Map]]
    },
    voiceStates: VoiceStateManager {
      cacheType: [Function: Collection],
      cache: Collection [Map] {},
      guild: [Circular]
    },
    deleted: false,
    available: true,
    id: '730762360272191508',
    shardID: 0,
    name: 'Serv sans nom',
    icon: null,
    splash: null,
    region: 'southafrica',
    memberCount: 6,
    large: false,
    features: [],
    applicationID: null,
    afkTimeout: 300,
    afkChannelID: null,
    systemChannelID: null,
    embedEnabled: undefined,
    premiumTier: 0,
    premiumSubscriptionCount: 0,
    verificationLevel: 'NONE',
    explicitContentFilter: 'DISABLED',
    mfaLevel: 0,
    joinedTimestamp: 1596429038364,
    defaultMessageNotifications: 'ALL',
    systemChannelFlags: SystemChannelFlags { bitfield: 0 },
    vanityURLCode: null,
    description: null,
    banner: null,
    rulesChannelID: null,
    publicUpdatesChannelID: null,
    ownerID: '380421367704584193',
      cacheType: [Function: Collection],
      cache: Collection [Map] {},
      guild: [Circular]
    }
  },
  messages: MessageManager {
    cacheType: [Function: LimitedCollection],
    cache: LimitedCollection [Map] { maxSize: 200 },
    channel: [Circular]
  },
  _typing: Map {}
}
```

The method I used to get the channel

```
Client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    console.log(db.get(`wl_channel`))
    const welcome = db.get(`wl_YN${member.guild.id}`)
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(`Welcome ***${member.displayName}***`)
    .setColor("#2163D7")
    .addFields({ name: `**${member.displayName}**`, value: 'Please read the **rules**'},{ name: `You are our ` , value: `***${member.guild.memberCount}*** th member!`})    
    .setImage(member.user.avatarURL())
    .setThumbnail(member.user.avatarURL())

    if(welcome === true){
        console.log(member.guild.channels.cache.get(db.get(`wl_channel`).id))
    }
});
```

How I saved the channel

```
db.set(`wl_channel`, message.mentions.channels.first().id)
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the channels name in the database:

```
db.set(`wl_channel`, message.mentions.channels.first().name)
```

Then obtain the channel using the following:

```
Client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    console.log(db.get(`wl_channel`))
    let welcomeChannel = db.get(`wl_channel`)
    const welcome = db.get(`wl_YN${member.guild.id}`)
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(`Welcome ***${member.displayName}***`)
    .setColor("#2163D7")
    .addFields({ name: `**${member.displayName}**`, value: 'Please read the **rules**'},{ name: `You are our ` , value: `***${member.guild.memberCount}*** th member!`})    
    .setImage(member.user.avatarURL())
    .setThumbnail(member.user.avatarURL())

    if(welcome === true){
        let channel = message.channels.find(channel => channel.name === welcomeChannel);
        channel.send(embed);
    }
});
```